# Delete Django model with AJAX call

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-admin

I am writing a photogallery app, which is using Django Rest Framework API.

I fill the data in Django models (images and descriptions) with said API using AJAX (specifically axios).

The question is - is it possible not only to POST data, but to delete it from my frontend app and I mean model instance - like it's done in the admin interface or even delete all model instances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can for example add a **`.delete(..)`** implementation as well:

```
class SomeModelDetail(APIView):

    def get_object(self, pk):
        try:
            return SomeModel.objects.get(pk=pk)
        except SomeModel.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

    # ...

    def delete(self, request, pk, format=None):
        self.get_object(pk).delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

The `HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT` response is thus a status code that is sometimes used to indicate that the corresponding object is now removed.

If we then add this view to the URL:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns
from app import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^somemodel/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.SomeModelDetail.as_view()),
]

format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns)
```

We can then make a `DELETE` AJAX call:

```
# JavaScript (Ajax request)

$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/someapp/somemodel/123/',
    type: 'DELETE',
    data: {},
    contentType:'application/json',
    dataType: 'text',
    error: function(result){},
    success: function(result) {}
});
```

We thus perform a `DELETE` method request, for a specific `somemodel` instance (here with primary key `123`, although you have to fill that in yourself with a sensical one).

Comment: Thank you! Your answer really hepled me, because I could not find any sane material on this matter.